# Will redirecting based on mobile/desktop user-agent cause SEO or caching issues?

Tags: seo, redirects, mobile

I have two versions of a website, the mobile version and the desktop version. Both websites are hosted on the same domain (`www.example.com`) and have a similar URL structure for most pages (`www.example.com/about` exists on both websites).

However some pages exist only on the desktop version (or vice versa), so I am able to setup a redirect from the non-existent URL to a related one on the other site based on the user agent (`www.example.com/desktop-only-page` will work if you have a desktop UA, but will 301 redirect to `www.example.com/related-page` for mobile UAs).

Will this setup result in issues (for example, if the 301 redirect is cached, or crawlers may not crawl as expected)?